# Get windows loader before Ubuntu Loader

Tags: 12.04, dual-boot, windows-7, bootloader

I have installed Ubuntu 12.04 in my computer with windows 7 on it. Most of my games are installed in windows.So I would usually load into windows.
After installing Ubuntu, it is the loader of Ubuntu that shows up before that of windows.
I this question I would like to know to make the windows loader to appear before that of windows and to have a link in the windows loader to the Ubuntu loader like the one that is in the Ubuntu Loader.

Answer (score 0):

This is not possible.
But you can use the "Grub Customizer".

Features:
* move, remove or rename menuentries (they stey updatable by update-grub)
* edit the contents of menuentries or create new ones (internally it edits the 40_custom)
* settings like default operating system, kernel params, background image and text colors etc.

Open the terminal and run the following commands

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:danielrichter2007/grub-customizer
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install grub-customizer
```

Comment: It is possible: Install ubuntu, copy MBR to a bin file with dd tool, install windows, copy MBR.bin file to windows partition C:\, point to the MBR.bin in Windows boot.ini. No, I am not going to explain every step. It is for experts only :P